# ListView and programmatically margin for rows

Tags: android, listview, layoutparams

I'm retrieving data from WebService and I use a custom adapter `ArrayAdapter` to populate my `listView`. For each row, I have to set a left or right margin depending webservice return. So my idea was using this following code :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);  // left margin
holder.mainContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);  // Here is the problem
```

mainContainer is a LinearLayout

In `getView` method I use the view hodler pattern

```
MessageHolder holder = null;

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(MessagesActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.thread_activity_listview_item, null);

    holder = new MessageHolder();
    holder.mainContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main_container);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (MessageHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

Here is my `xml` for a row :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_left_corner_discussion_on"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/updated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But with this code, I have the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

I precise, I can't use padding in my situation. Moreover if I use `AbsListView.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, I can't set margin anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Post the Main `XML` code that contain the ListView itself please

Comment: Also the logic that contain your intialization for the ListView and the holder elements

Comment: I've edited my code but I'm not sure these informations are very useful. I know it exists other question about it but I didn't find any solution

Comment: This might help you, [LinearLayout's margin is being ignored if used as ListView row view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16278769/593709)

Comment: @AdilSoomro : So there is no way to add margins ?

Comment: @aat you need to use another outer `LinearLayout` to get it worked.

Comment: @AdilSoomro Yes this is the only solution I've found.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to dynamically set margin for a `ListView` row view. As a hack what you can do is split your row layout in to two parts as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout>

<--!Blank layout which acts as margin, set weight to 10-->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout>
 <--!Move the code for your row here, set weight to 90-->
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Provide ids for your child `LinearLayouts` so that you can access them in code. Since the view group you access is linear layout you can set the weight of them in code.

Comment: You change the layout of the adapter to set margin on a row, this is possible.

Comment: @Booger Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16278769/1186983 . `AbsListView.LayoutParams` doesnt include margin support. And I guess OP has tried that.

Comment: Well, I am suggesting that OP not set List params, and instead set this in the adapter.  You don't need the workaround you are suggesting.  I think it is a bad idea to add empty layouts, as spacers (creates extra view containers, which is non-performant).  Peace.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
holder.mainContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main_container);
    LayoutParams params = holer.mainContainer.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0); 
    holder.mainContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

you need to get params from view and just add margin to it.

Comment: `holer.mainContainer` is not null but `holer.mainContainer.getLayoutParams()` is.

Answer (score 0):

First you should get :

```
ListView lstView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Then :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpimgHeader = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(lstView.getLayoutParams());
```

finally :

```
lpimgHeader.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); <== Insert size margins
lstView.setLayoutParams(lpimgHeader);
```

Notice : Custom `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` .