# How to set the spacing in listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to make a list view like this:
[Listview I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Hki.png)

I tried the following ways:

1. By setting this in the list view but it is not working

   ```
   android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
   android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
   ```
2. By setting the `marginTop` in the textview layout but it is also not working.

So some one can help me how to get the required output.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342461/margin-on-listview-items-in-android)  and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984313/spacing-between-listview-items-android), but these are not working.

This is my custom listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<View
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Text"
    />
<View
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:background="#fff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post more details about your ListView? Does it have a custom view(xml file)?

Comment: I have updated the question @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: don't use **SP** as with these attributes. it is used for font size. for more check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android

Comment: I have tried that one but I use dp mostly

Comment: **IMHO** you should use `RecyclerView with CardView` instead of using that **OLD** `ListView`. That only will give you [YOUR DESIRED LISTVIEW](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Hki.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, use this. It should turn out exactly as you want. Fell free to change margins and padding.

In your custom ListView layout, use this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#009688">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_imageView1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, inside your drawable folder create a new xml, call it rectangle. Paste the code below in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

The radius defines the curves of the rectangle you want, feel free to change it as you wish.

Use the custom ListView layout in your adapter. This should work.

Happy coding... cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust your ListView for each item to like this example :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Large Text" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the result, just adding some margin to the parent layout and put an empty view to take up an 8dp space so that the next item of the view will be 8dp away form the first one and so one.

[image]

Comment: it worked but Its not what I want I tried to set the View in both the side too but it is not working

Comment: you mean you put it before and after the textview ? and what was the result ?

Comment: the second image is the output I am getting the left and right view are not working I set the background  also it worked only for the last view

Comment: try add a 4dp margin to your ListView in the activity's layout xml